# Persistent errors in Magento 2 make the installation unusable

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions

I am developing an extension for magento 2.1.5. In development phase, when my module has certain errors for example schema validation errors or generic php errors or naive developer mistakes, my magento installable is unable to recover from them. Even if I remove the whole module that I was working on from app/code/ directory, I still see the same errors.

The magento commands for setup, clearing cache start throwing the same error and my installation becomes unusable. I can not open the admin portal as well.

I have tried clearing the cache from var/cache and generation directories without any success. Also tried disabling the module manually. Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so finally figured it out. I just deleted the whole var directory everytime I made code changes, and voila! It worked!